# Array out of bounds Exception bowling example

Tags: java

Hi guys can someone please tell me what this means? I'm writing a program for a game of bowling and my program compiles with no errors but when I run it , this part of the code is highlighted with the error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:-1`

Here is my code:

```
if(rolls[i]+rolls[i+1] == 10) {
    total = rolls[i]+rolls[i+1];
    isSpare = true;
}
```

Edit: Here is the entire for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rolls.length; i += 2) {
    isStrike = false;
    isSpare = false;
    lastFrame = false;
    if (i == rolls.length - 3) {
        System.out.println("FINAL FRAME");
        lastFrame = true;
        total = rolls[i] + rolls[i + 1] + rolls[i + 2];
        frame[0] = rolls[i];
        frame[1] = rolls[i + 1];
        frame[2] = rolls[i + 2];
    }
    if (rolls[i] == 10) {
        total = rolls[i];
        frame[0] = rolls[i];
        isStrike = true;
        i -= 1;
    } else {
        total = rolls[i] + rolls[i + 1];
        frame[0] = rolls[i];
        frame[1] = rolls[i + 1];
    }
    if (rolls[i] + rolls[i + 1] == 10) {
        total = rolls[i] + rolls[i + 1];
        isSpare = true;
    }
    runningTotal = runningTotal + total;
    printFrame(frame, isStrike, isSpare, lastFrame, frames, runningTotal);
    frames++;
} //increment

System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Not enough code. Show us your loop.

Comment: what is the outer loop of this IF condition?

Comment: I am guessing that this is within a for-loop and that's where the "i" comes from like for(int i=0; i < rolls.length; i++) so this loop doesn't go out of bonds but when you say "i+1" at the last iteration i is less than length, but when you add the +1 it breaks it. try for(int i=0; i < rolls.length-1; i++)

Comment: Sorry, i've added in my for loop

Comment: You can't call rolls[i+1] when i takes you up to the last element of the array. For an odd number of rolls, this will fall over for sure. AND you're changing the value of i inside your loop. Don't ever do that. Use a temp variable if you wish, but don't affect the iterator itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(rolls[i]==10){
    total=rolls[i];
    frame[0]=rolls[i];
    isStrike=true;
    i-=1;
}
```

In your first iteration, if rolls[0] happens to be 10, you are reducing i by 1 making it -1. The next if-statement will then throw an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "i" was initialized with -1, therefore you are trying to access an invalid slot on the array.

Comment: I think that it was initlized with -1 as rolls[i] is evaluated first

Comment: thanks for your comment, i've just included in the entire for loop

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few bugs in this code. First, let me somewhat reiterate what @Thomas said, by adding to it,

```
if (rolls[i] == 10) {
    total = rolls[i];
    frame[0] = rolls[i];
    isStrike = true;
    i -= 1;
}
```

Say, `rolls[0] = 10`; `i` is set to -1. In the following block,

```
if (rolls[i] + rolls[i + 1] == 10) {
    total = rolls[i] + rolls[i + 1];
    isSpare = true;
}
```

you are trying to access `rolls[-1]` and `rolls[0]`. Hence the issue.

Secondly, I don't know if this is a flaw in your logic, but I thought I should point this out. `i -= 1;` will reduce the `i` by 1. On the next iteration of the loop, `i++` occurs **before** entering the loop body. So, you are, in essence, *stuck* at the same index, and I don't understand why you would want that.

Thirdly, trying to access `i+1` in a loop that takes you till the last element of the array will result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the last index.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i'm still unsure as to how i'm supposed to correct the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @CH26 Could you give me an idea about your entire plan? I would be better able to suggest a fix once I have a better idea of what the goal is.

Answer (score -2):

It fails when trying to get the value of `rolls[i+1]` assuming that at that moment "i" is equal to the maximum amount of elements on the array.

Comment: Index `-1` is very unlikely to happen in `rolls[i+1]`.

Comment: It's a valid comment, but not a valid answer. For an array with an odd number of elements, rolls[i+1] will fall over, given the increment of 2 in the iterator. However, there's more bugs in here (esp. i -= 1) that are causing compounded issues resulting in the out of bounds exception.

Comment: Only post answers if you understand the question properly. Please don't start your answer with -  *"The reason could probably be..."* or end it with - *"it is hard to tell without complete code"*.